# FileExists is false at network drives when UAC is used?

Tags: delphi, uac

I have found following issue with a CLI tool that accepts files via drag'n'drop.

The file X:\MyApp.exe is a CLI tool which requires UAC elevation (which will be granted).

The operating system is Win7 32-bit.

X: is a network drive to a NAS.

When I drag X:\MyDLL.dll into X:\MyApp.exe , FileExists(ParamStr(1)) will be false. RaiseLastOSError() will show code 3. What am I doing wrong?

It does work when the source file is stored at C: (and dragged into the EXE file).

```
WriteLn('ParamStr 1 = '+ParamStr(1)); // X:\MyDLL.dll
if not FileExists(ParamStr(1)) then
begin
  try
    RaiseLastOSError;
  except
    on E: exception do
    begin
      Writeln(E.message); // (Translated) System error 3. The file could not be found.
    end;
  end;
  exit;
end;
```

Comment: Does it work with no elevation?

Comment: I think the drive is not seen as mapped for the application in it's elevated state.

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using? Depending on version, `FileExists()` may attempt different approaches to try to resolve existence for different types of paths. Also, when elevating the app in UAC, are you using the same user account, or logging in to a different user account? Mapped drive letters are user-specific, so if you are elevating as a different user, it may not even know about the `X:` drive at all.

Comment: I compiled using Delphi XE4. The elevation is enforced using a manifest resource. Since I am already logged in an account with administrator privileges (in a RDP connection), I just had to click "Yes" in the UAC dialog.  Since the user is the same,  I assume that the network drive mapping should still exist?

Comment: @rinntech Not necessarily. Mapped drives are one of those things that don't always exist. Even if its the same user. For example, if I have a service that is logged in under a specific user and try and access a drive that is mapped for the same user but who is logged onto the desktop then it won't work.

Comment: if I recall this is an  issue with the os and drive mappings  with uac

Comment: @Graymatter Thank you very much for your answer. I did not came to that idea since I thought the reason was either my code, the Delphi RTL, Windows or the Drag'n'Drop action. After I simply opened an elevated cmd.exe with the same user, the drive X: was not available. (This issue is discussed at http://superuser.com/questions/495370/why-isnt-a-mapped-drive-available-under-an-elevated-cmd-prompt-but-is-under-a-r ) Can you please post an answer to this thread, so I can accept it as solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An elevated application does see the mapped drives for the user. This is similar to a service logging in under a user account and the user logging into the desktop with the same user account. The service won't be able to see the user's mapped drives.

A work around for this type of situation is to create a service that runs with the permissions you require and then a standard application that runs non-elevated. The application sends messages to the service so that it can perform the actions that need elevation.

Comment: You should also be able to set the [EnableLinkedConnections registry value](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844140.aspx).